# I tried solving this problem by using MAX function but get the result . Is there a way to solve it by using any other function?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I need to get "second updated_time" for each order and sorting them by "update_time". I wrote the following query, which is not giving any output.

Suppose, we have to calculate get the time difference between second updated time and first updated time against each order_id ,if we sort the table on update_time (same question but extended)
Server is Mysql. The TIMEDIFF() function will be applied, but how? It am trying this:

**select order_history.*,order_history.TIMEDIFF(
from (select order_history.*,
row_number() OVER (partition by order_id order by update_time) as seqnum
from order_history
) order_history
where seqnum = 2
order by update_time;**

**select update_time <MAX(update_time)
from order_history
order by update_time desc;**

[The attached image shows the orders_history (table for the problem)]

Comment: Sorry, but could you please show the table structure, sample data and desired output

Comment: did you try doing a subquery? something like select update_time < (select MAX(update_time) from order_history) from order_history order by update_time desc

Comment: Tag your question with the databse you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get "second updated_time" for each order and sorting them by "update_time".

This sounds like:

```
select oh.*
from (select oh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by order_id order by update_toime) as seqnum
      from order_history oh
     ) oh
where seqnum = 2
order by update_time;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It works now. Its just that seqnum =2

Comment: @SARVESHJOSHI . . . Good catch.  That would be the right meaning of "second".